# DateTime CreateFromFormat returning non object

Tags: php, datetime

I am attempting to run this code. It works perfectly when the time is put in manually but when i attempt to put the time in with the variable $getTime it doesn't seem to work. I am checking if it works by checking if $utc_date is an object.

```
$getTime = rawurldecode($_GET['time']);
$utc_date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d G:i',
    $getTime,
    new DateTimeZone(get_timezone($_GET['tz']))
);

if (!is_object($utc_date)) {
    echo 'Error: Invalid Time Data'.' - '.$getTime;
}else{
    //Other Stuff
}
```

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($getTime);` ?

Comment: `string(20) "27-04-2011, 02:45:00"`

Comment: Update `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i',` into `DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s',`

Comment: @Mattigins Your format doesn't match your date. Use `d-m-Y, H:i:s` instead

Comment: Ah, thanks @Uchiha that got it sorted (once i added the ,)

Comment: Yep you're right the one with comma I've didn't seen that comma @Rizier123